# ssh: connect to host on port 22: Connection refused

Tags: azure, ssh

I have looked around for answers but didn't not able to find solution related to my query.

I was able to ssh the server earlier but after a reboot I was not able to. I checked Azure portal for the instance it was showing status as Running. I tried rebooting it a couple of times but I was not able to ssh. I checked further and found out that the public IP shown was different this time. I tried with that IP but still not able to login.

Any suggestion what I should I do next. Also, how can I make the IP static in Azure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please start from the [official SSH connection troubleshooting guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-troubleshoot-ssh-connection/) - most of the SSH issues i had (and yours situation is the same i had a few times) were solved by reset-ssh way. Helpful would be to see the serial console output (VM dashboard => Settings).

The fact that your IP changed is normal if you did not reserve that, it will change.

Comment: Thanks Alex, resetting SSH using command **azure vm reset-access -g YourResourceGroupName -n YourVirtualMachineName -r** via Azure CLI worked. +1

Comment: Glad it works. Please mark your question answered for a future reference, if that was helpful - that question is often.

Comment: link for the guide is dead